# Does it make sense to use DI container in front end javascript app

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, reactjs, inversion-of-control

I am designing an app with React and its supporting libraries ecosystem. It's going to be a large app, with lots of services and helper modules. To handle the dependency between them, does it make sense to use DI container.

**[Update]**

Please add missing problems/solutions we have available to prepare a good guideline to include/exclude DI container

Few problems that DI container tries to solve are

It enables easy plug and play of modules
 Changes in constructor of the modules are limited to service registration

Without using DI container, I have following options

We use factory modules(initaliser) which just instantiate, this will enable plug, different module with same interface and wont require change where it is consumed.

To make it singleton, service module will export instance of it, so that same instance is referred wherever its included.

One thing which will be missing though is single place(registry) where we can find all the dependencies of different modules.

Comment: This will probably get closed for being opinion-based. That said, as someone who has to use Angular 1.x at work, I would say it's not worth it - it just gets in the way more than anything. In my opinion, you're better off just using a good module bundler like Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: Rather than opinion, I think the real use, developer experience like yours, and end result achieved after implementing it should try to answer it.

Comment: Yeah, for what it's worth, I didn't flag the question, as I wasn't 100% sure if it fell under that category. I think the answer that best articulates how I feel is FailedUnitTest's one - DI is a solution to a problem, not something that should be used in every single application. This is why I prefer React personally; design patterns like that are opt-in, rather than forced upon every project.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the case. If app is small then probably no. If app requirements changes often, you use SOLID approach and TS then it makes bit more sense.

It's like asking "Is car good to drive to work?". But we don't know how far is it for you to get from your home to work, do you have where to park, how much are you going spend on gas vs what is the public transportation ticket cost etc...

In general DI helps making code open for extensions but closed for modifications (Open/Close principle). It's always good idea to create high quality code. Sadly from busineess point of view DI in simple projects it will be waste of time and it will make steeper learning curve for frontend people.

Comment: Yes we plan to use TS, and requirements will be changing. The app size in terms of helper libraries, components, reducers is large. Which by your suggestion qualifies for DI.

Comment: What DI trully gives you is a "easy way of changing components", like in the car - you can easily change the tire/radio. Even changing an engine is possible - only requirement is that interchanged components have to implement same interface. For example if you change the radio the connection socket has to be same.
Then if you implement all services properly it will be easy to change app components (for example change chat integration from intercom to desk.com) - Easy means you just create a new service and inject it, you don't have to change the code in all classes in order to make it work

Comment: For example Angular1.x is using a DI and it works really well

Comment: I too liked analogy, and understood the use, I am trying to compare it with usual  "import"/ "require".

Comment: idea is that you have one configuration where you keep all dependencies, everywhere in code you do `var chat = container['chatService'];` or `var db = container['databaseRepository']`; Then in one place in you register your `chatService` or `databaseRepository`. Thats all. If you go with import/require then if you want to change chart/db you have to modify all files where you have the import/require statement

Comment: Got the idea behind i.e.  **one configuration where you keep all dependencies**.  Another way to solve the problem of instantiating these services with modified constructor is having simple factory modules which just instantiate. Like DI if we keep interfaces same wherever we use these services it wont affect. Individual service will be modified as result of constructor change and to have it singleton it will just export instance of it.